# 1995 Camry LE rim and tire swap with 2012

Tags: toyota, tires, camry, wheels

I have a '95 Camry as well as a 2012 Camry which is paid off, but totaled (no collision). I'd just bought brand new tires a month before. Is there any way possible that I can put the 2012 size 16 rims and tires onto my '95 Camry with size 14 rims and tires? What would I have to do?

Comment: I think you don't need to change anything as the 95 model seems to accepts the  16 rims and both have the same bolt pattern. See the link below https://www.wheel-size.com/size/toyota/camry/1995/      and     https://www.wheel-size.com/size/toyota/camry/2012/

Answer (score 4):

There are several things to consider when swapping wheels from one vehicle to another.

First and foremost, does the wheel [PCD](https://konigwheels.com/wheel-info-tech/what-is-pcd/) match between vehicles? In your case, yes, according to [this website](https://www.wheel-size.com), both the 1995 and the 2012 Toyota Camry wheels have the same PCD (5 x 114.3).

Secondly, does the hub centre bore match? According to the above website, the 2012 vehicle has a centre bore of 60.1mm and there is no info for the 1995 vehicle. It is highly probable that the 1995 vehicle either has the same centre bore (or, much less likely, has lug centric wheel mounting) In either case, this will not present a problem.

Thirdly, does the offset match? It is not crucial that the offsets match, but if there is a wide divergence between the two, the wheels may not be laterally positioned correctly which may cause handling issues and/or the tyres fouling on the car bodywork, the brake caliper or drum, or some other part. The above gives an offset of 40mm for the 1995 vehicle, and 45mm for the 2012 vehicle, so - in my opinion - nothing to worry about there either.

Also to consider is the relative circumference of the wheels. I do not know the exact size of the tyres you have fitted but for example, the factory fitment on the 1995 Camry are 185/70R14 which have a circumference of 76". The 2012 are 205/65R16 which have a circumference of 83.2". But what does this mean? with the larger wheels, your speedometer becomes inaccurate. For example, when your speedometer reads 50mpg, you are actually travelling at 54.8mph. Aside from the obvious, there may be consequences come inspection time depending on your jurisdiction.

You can use [this website](https://tiresize.com/tyre-size-calculator/) to calculate the difference in circumference between two different tyre sizes.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!  Nice answer.